# how to find number of arguments expected by an elisp function in emacs

Tags: functions, arguments

I have some code that I use in my .emacs file that works with version 25.5 where the definition of windows--sanitize-window-sizes looks something like this:

```
(defun window--sanitize-window-sizes (frame horizontal) ;; emacs 25.5
```

That I want to make work both there and in emacs 27.1 where the definition of windows--sanitize-window-sizes looks something like this:

```
(defun window--sanitize-window-sizes (horizontal) ;; emacs 27.1
```

So, how do I check in my calling function how many arguments the function expects, what do I write to ask this question, as in:

```
   (cond
     ((not (fboundp 'window--sanitize-window-sizes))
      t ; no function to call, assume sizes ok
      )
      ((= (max-number-of-arguments 'window--sanitize-window-sizes) 1)
       ;; probably something like (cdr (arguments-accepted 'window--sanitize-window-sizes))
       (window--sanitize-window-sizes size) ; 27.1 expects only size 
       )
      (t
       (window--sanitize-window-sizes frame size) ; 25.5 expects only size 
       )
      )
```

I presume there is a function I can apply to a symbol that tells me how many
arguments are expected (min max) or maybe something more complex to handle `&optional` and `&rest` cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2nd Edit: Turns out there is a builtin, `func-arity`. It works exactly like the `lambda-arity` included below. Might be worth checking if it's defined in your emacs 25 though.

1st Edit: having re-read your use-case, maybe just do `(if (< (string-to-number emacs-version) ...` instead.

---

Not built-in, no. There's `help-function-arglist` which returns the signature, such as `(arg1 &optional arg2 &rest args)`.

Luckily, EmacsWiki has a parser for this, relevant code extracted from

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/parser-fn.el

```
(require 'help-fns)

(defun lambda-arity (function)
  "Return minimum and maximum number of args allowed for FUNCTION.
FUNCTION must be a symbol whose function binding is a lambda expression
or a macro.
The returned value is a pair (MIN . MAX).  MIN is the minimum number
of args.  MAX is the maximum number or the symbol `many', for a lambda
or macro with `&rest' args."
  (let* ((arglist (help-function-arglist function))
         (optional-arglist (memq '&optional arglist))
         (rest-arglist (memq '&rest arglist)))
    (cons (- (length arglist)
             (cond (optional-arglist (length optional-arglist))
                   (rest-arglist (length rest-arglist))
                   (t 0)))
          (cond (rest-arglist 'many)
                (optional-arglist (+ (length arglist)
                                     (length optional-arglist)
                                     -1))
                (t (length arglist))))))

(defun function-arity ( function )
  (if (subrp function)
    (subr-arity function)
    (lambda-arity function)))
```

Comment: `func-arity` was added in 26.1: https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/be3267eb346745d73cfb627c6e962e261a51d6d2/etc/NEWS.26#L1556

Answer (score 1):

In addition to function `func-arity` (which @Tommy mentioned), there is function `subr-arity`, for functions defined in C source code, not Lisp.  `C-h f subr-arity` says:

> `subr-arity` is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> `(subr-arity SUBR)`
>
> Return minimum and maximum number of args allowed for `SUBR`.
>
> `SUBR` must be a built-in function.
> The returned value is a pair `(MIN . MAX)`.  `MIN` is the minimum number
> of args.  `MAX` is the maximum number or the symbol `many`, for a
> function with `&rest` args, or `unevalled` for a special form.

Answer (score 0):

Check the actual Emacs version, and act based on what you know to be correct for that version.

Just knowing how many arguments are expected is insufficient.  Imagine that the function changes again in future to add a second argument which is different to the original second argument -- you don't want your code to get the two mixed up.

You can test `(version< emacs-version VERSION-STRING)` or just `(< emacs-major-version INTEGER)` if that's sufficient (which is fairly likely with API changes).

Comment: Ah! I thought there oughta be something better than `(string-to-number emacs-version)`. I wonder why it's not a float in the first place..?

Comment: Floats are imprecise in any case, but a version can be more than simply `X.Y`.  The current stable release of Emacs is 27.1, but the development version was 27.0.50, and in general version strings may contain suffixes like `alpha1`, `beta3`, and `rc2`.

Comment: Actually, that's what I ended up doing.  I'm not particularly happy with that, because sometimes, I tweak the code myself and add arguments, which means the version isn't a safe way to get the "signature" of a function, but then it is lisp and not a strongly typed language.